# Change password with RESTful authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, restful-authentication

OK, I've been having relative success with RESTful authentication. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.railslodge.com/plugins/75-restful-authentication/documentations/1-change-password) to add the capability to change the password. The problem is that tutorial is written for rails 2.3 and I'm using rails 3.

The code used in my controller and view are exactly as they are [in the tutorial](http://www.railslodge.com/plugins/75-restful-authentication/documentations/1-change-password)

I added to routes.rb:

```
  match '/change_password' => 'users#change_password', :as => :change_password
  resources :users, :controller => 'users', :collection => {:change_password_update => :put}
```

Now i get this error: undefined method `change_password_update_user_path'

the comments to the tutorial mentioned that exact error, and they said the solution is in the routing, but given the routing differences between 2.3 and 3, I'm really just guessing what needs to go in there. Any idea how i can get this working?

Answer (score 0):

all i had to do is change

```
<% form_tag change_password_update_user_path(current_user), :method => :put do |f| %>
```

to

```
<% form_tag '/change_password_update', :method => :put do |f| %>
```

and put this in my routes.rb

```
match '/change_password' => 'users#change_password', :as => :change_password
match '/change_password_update' => 'users#change_password_update', :as => :change_password_update
resources :users, :controller => 'users', :collection => {:change_password_update => :put}
```